# substring function not recognized

Tags: split, substring

I have some JS code to process the name of the HTML file and extract a substring as follows:

```
var pstr = "";
var xname = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
pstr = xname.substring(5,6);
alert (pstr);
```

xname  successfully stores the name of the file such as  FileN1Name.html but the substring operation following fails and the following error is displayed in the Chrome developer console saying that xname.substring is not a function with an Uncaught TypeError.   [Developer console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ocRi.png)

Tried using developer console for more info as described.

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` method in JavaScript returns an array, and even though you're using `slice(-1)` to get the last item, it's still returned as an array. Arrays don't have a `substring` method, hence you're seeing the error `xname.substring is not a function`.

To fix the issue, you need to extract the string from the array before calling `substring`. You can use array indexing to get the first (and only) element:

```
var pstr = "";
var xname = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0];   
// Add [0] here
pstr = xname.substring(5,6);
alert (pstr);
```

This code now gets the last segment of the URL path (your HTML file name), and extracts the substring from index 5 to 6. If `xname` is `"FileN1Name.html"`, `pstr` will be `"1"`. Note that JavaScript uses zero-based indexing, so the 5th index is actually the 6th character.